# Install Scalate in Play (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, scalate

I was following the instructions here to install scalate for my project

http://www.playframework.org/modules/scalate-0.1/home

And here's a controller from my app

```
package controllers {

  import play._
  import play.mvc._

  object Home extends ScalateController {

    def index = {

    }

  }
}
```

However, when I reloaded, I got the error "not found: type ScalateController". Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.